# Don't want TouchPhase.Ended to execute

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity,but still...:)
**Here What i need:**
When i tap on the screen (press and release),my console should say  "Do material"
When i move (touch,move,release),my console should say ONLY lots of "Do Rotation"
**What i have:**
When i tap on the screen (press and release),my console says "Do material"
When i move (touch,move,release),my console says lots of  "Do Rotation"    AND "Do material" when i release my finger.
Pls help me to figure out how stop executing TouchPhase.Ended after my TouchPhase.Moved

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1)
            {
                t = Input.GetTouch (0);
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved )
                Debug.Log ("Do Rotation");

                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && t.tapCount == 1 ) 
                Debug.Log ("Do Material");
            }
```

thank you in advance for your quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use a bool you can get the results your looking for, im pretty sure i havent tryed it, something like

```
public bool touched = false;
if (Input.touchCount == 1)
            {
                t = Input.GetTouch (0);
                if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Began){
                touched = true;
                }
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved ){
                Debug.Log ("Do Rotation");
                touched = false;
                }

                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && t.tapCount == 1 && touched) 
                Debug.Log ("Do Material");
            }
```